# Which file extensions are affected by ColdFusion's Trusted Cache

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfimport

Which file extensions are cached by Trusted Cache?  CFM and CFC are obvious ones, but what about CFR?  Are there are other file extensions that are caught by Trusted Cache?

Some places I know/suspect that files enter the template cache are:

- directly specified in the url (`cfm`, `cfml`, `cfc`, more?)
- cfinclude (any file extension that is used in a cfinclude e.g. `<cfinclude template="./some.css">`)
- cfmodule (`cfm`, more?)
- cfimport (`cfm`, also `jar` and `tld`?)
- cfobject, createobject (`cfc`, also .net, com, java, and web services?)
- cfreport (`cfr` which can be complied with cfcompile utility?)

Are there other tags that will have the same effect of adding content into the template cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't an official source for this information.  However, it is possible, with a lot of work, to test each and every tag to see if the files end up in the Trusted Cache.

Your first two bullet points are covered by [Shawn Holmes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8272794/238592) and [Sean Corfield's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8330351/238592), respectively.

Bullet 3: cfmodule is limited to cfm files, so that extension is the only one you have to worry about there.

Bullet 6: cfreport shouldn't enter the template cache, since it's converting the file, not compiling it for code to execute.

Answer (score 7):

Adobe ColdFusion (and Railo) compile CFML templates to JVM bytecode and, if configured to do so, will write the compiled class(es) to disk as .class files. The template cache is a mechanism for saying: if the target class is already loaded, don't bother looking at the (source) file on disk to see if it needs recompilation - trust what's in memory.

Recent enhancements to ACF and Railo allow you to specify that (source) files can be checked always (not trusted), once per request, never (always trusted).

That shouldn't be news to anyone.

Obviously ACF and Railo will compile any .cfm or .cfc file they are asked to process so those will "end up" in the trusted cache if it is enabled.

If you cfinclude a file - any file - ACF and Railo will also compile that to JVM bytecode (and create a .class file on disk if configured to do so). Since an included file is compiled, it will also "end up" in the trusted cache. What happens if you include a CSS file then? It gets compiled to bytecode that outputs the entire content of the CSS file as a string to the response stream. Since it is a compiled class, that now outputs a hardcoded string, if you change the CSS source file and have trusted cache enabled, ACF and Railo will trust what's in the classloader and not recompile it (assuming "never" check source is the admin setting).

You can verify this by cleaning out the cfclasses folder, restarting your CFML engine and running your code. You'll see a .class file appear for your CSS file (assuming you have save class files to disk enabled).

So, cfinclude forces compilation of "any" file and the normal rules of trusted cache apply for classes loaded into memory.

I no longer use ACF so I can't speak in detail to .cfr files (Railo does not support report files) but it will most likely depend on whether ACF compiles a .cfr file or not. It should be easy to verify (by looking in the cfclasses folder).

Comment: Thank you! +1 for The missing link, I've removed my answer.

Comment: That all makes sense and correlates to data found elsewhere on the web, what I can't find is details about what can get into the template cache, and how. Some other areas where I know/suspect templates enter from are: direct loading from webserver as per @ShawnHolmes original answer, cfinclude, cfmodule, cfimport (`jar`s and `tld`s as well as `cfm`s?), cfobject (`cfc`s, but .net, com, java, and web services?), createobject, cfreport (`cfr` can be complied with cfcompile utility), others? Also, I don't think ACF always writes the .class files. Ran tests and only had one .class instead of 4.

Comment: @ShawnHolmes Shame you removed the original part of your answer, I thought that was a very valuable part of the answer to this question.

Comment: I didn't want to cloud the correct answer with mine, but I'll return it for view/reference, sans the botched part.

Answer (score 5):

By default, ColdFusion ships with the *.cfm, *.cfc, and *.cfml extensions mapped in JRun as the extensions that are trusted. You may view these mappings by opening up the j2ee-web.xml and web.xml config files in \JRun4\servers\cfusion\cfusion-ear\cfusion-war\WEB-INF\ (or near this, based on your installation):

```
<servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_3">
    <servlet-name>CfmServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.cfm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_4">
    <servlet-name>CFCServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.cfc</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_5">
    <servlet-name>CfmServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.cfml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

However, you can also manually configure brand-new mappings here as well, which will allow ColdFusion to parse/compile CFML tags in files with a different extension as well (I've worked with CF Servers that have been configured to parse .shtml, for example)

Note: You'll also have to do some additional configuration for your web server, be it Apache, IIS, or whatever.

Once CF is configured to handle a file of a particular extension, it is added to the list of files that is processed in the Trusted Cache--since that file ultimately equates to a compiled .class file under-the-hood.

Comment: I've addded another case I've discovered when content can get into the template cache.  Do you have further insights?

Comment: The link you provided is an example of an app-level object being cached, while continuing to dynamically execute the body of its method/pseudo-constructor, which in turn, is a CFINCLUDE. This is analogous to my *Situation B* above. The object and method is cached, but what the method produces when called is not. This has no bearing on the Trusted Cache, which is an entirely separate process CF uses to examine/ignore CF templates for modification/recompilation.

Comment: We're still not speaking the same language. I am going to re-think how I approach this, and update my original answer shortly.

Comment: The original answer still stands: Only pages with the above mappings are added to the trusted cache. The footnote you take away from this is: If any of those mappings call cfinclude and point to a file that *is not in those mappings* (ie. CSS, TXT, etc.), the file is contextually included (rather than evaluated) and thus, made a part of the Trusted Cache as well. Just be sure you are clear on that last part: some.css isn't physically placed in the trusted cached; its *contents* are, because it was cfincluded in a CF template.

Comment: Because calling clearTrustedCache('path\to\file\includesomecss.cfm') refreshes the code in the cf template, not the evaluation (savedcontent) of any includes that they point to. In order for the content itself to be refreshed (as it isn't dynamic, but has been integrated into the template contextually), you call clearTrustedCache('path\to\file\some.css'). Notice that if, instead of using <cfinclude>, you use the HTML <style> tag to include the css, its content will not be incorporated into the trusted cache.

Comment: I don't know how else to explain it--I've tried to be clear and concise about a) answering your original question and b) clarifying what exceptions to a) allow a file to make its way into the Trusted Cache--and I think I've covered it pretty comprehensively at this point. However, you continue to point to specific sentences, and then refer them to a blog post which is unrelated (but you believe it *is* related because it has "cfinclude" and "cache" in the blog title)--they are speaking app-level caching, you are asking about the "Trusted Cache", and I am unsure of how else to explain it.

Comment: I've re-clarified the entire answer, question by question. Please give it another top-to-bottom read and see if it addresses all outstanding issues.

Comment: You may have misunderstood my comments on that blog post. I've posted a separate answer to this question which I hope clarifies and corrects things.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the correct portion re: mappings, and up-voted yours Sean, which clarified the remaining part.

Comment: I've updated the question again to remove the less question like aspects.  Your comment answer now directly answers the _more_ on bullet one.  Cheers.